# Unable to cast an int64_to to a const void ptr

Tags: c

I use a C program to call a NASM program.  On return, NASM passes a pointer to an array buffer back to C.  I want to write that array buffer to file with fwrite.  To do that, I need to cast the int64_t returned by NASM to a const void *ptr for fwrite.  Here is what I have tried so far:

```
const void *output_ptr = rp;
const void *output_ptr = *(const void)rp;
const void *output_ptr = *(const void *ptr)rp;
*output_ptr = *(const void *ptr)rp;
```

but none of those work.  This seems like it should be a simple question, but searching on the internet and Stack Overflow didn't bring up any answers.

Here is the file write code:

```
FILE *fp = fopen (output_file.bin, "wb");
if (fp == NULL  )
    return -1;
fwrite (output_ptr, 8, length, fp);
fclose (fp);
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: "none of those work" is a meaningless statement.  What **do** they do?

Comment: In the last snippet (which was missing a `"` and a recent edit removed the other `"`) `fwrite()` doesn't care what type of data you want to write, because its argument is `const void *buffer`. So why go to the trouble of casting to `output_ptr`? You also asked it to write `length` elements each of size `8` which looks suspicious, but without more context can't be known.

Comment: You could make your question clearer by providing error messages and other stuff, as usual in [mcve]. Doesn't matter much now, because people managed to understand the problem without these details.

Comment: Just write it like you have written this question. "the int64_t": `the_int64_t` "cast the int64_t": `()the_int64_t` "cast the int64_t to a const void *ptr": `(const void*)the_int64_t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form of a cast operation is `(type) operand`.

The type for a pointer to a `const`-qualified `void` is `const void *`, not `const void` (which is not a pointer) or `const void *ptr` (which has an identifier in it, `ptr`, that is not part of a type).

So you want `(const void *) rp`.

Comment: So my complete line is "const void * output_ptr = (const void *) rp;" and that does work.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was wondering why `const void *output_ptr = rp;` wouldn't work.  Seems like it should have per [6.3.2.3p5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: 6.3.2.3 5 says the conversion is defined. It does not say it will be performed by default. The constraints in 6.5.16.1 1 (for simple assignment but which apply to initialization too), says what combinations of left and right operands you can have, and, in them, a pointer on the left has to have a pointer or null pointer constant on the right. So, if you want the conversion from a `uintptr_t`, you have to use a cast.